# Telling string to equal an int in android studio

Tags: java, android, string, int

Basically, I'm creating an app where users choose pass, merit or distinction for 18 different units (school basically). My problem is that I can't figure out how to tell the spinner that if the string in it is "Pass", that string equals the integer 70 (Merit = 80 and distinction = 90). I am using a string array and adapters for the spinners. I am currently trying to do this with an If statement:

```
if (spinner1.toString().equals("Pass")){}
```

I just have no idea what I should do to tell the string to equal an int.

To reiterate, I want Pass to = 70, Merit = 80, Distinction = 90.

Any guidance and help on this is much appreciated. :)

Comment: Search for `HashMap`...

Comment: you are only testing "Pass". Where do you have 70, 80 or 90?

Comment: You should read the tutorials on types again -- it seems like there's a misunderstanding here how the type system works. We can't tell what you're trying to do but a string is not an int. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: @user140547 it's not a duplicate. Please read the question again.

Comment: Stultuske, that's what I want pass merit and distinction to equal, I mentioned that in my question. and thanks Prerak, I will have a look, see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps, it's a little vague...
you mean, you have a few string<->int conversion to do?

```
public YourConstructor() {
    /*Map<String, Integer>*/ theMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    theMap.put("Pass", 10);
    theMap.put("Merit", 70);
    theMap.put("distinction ", 90);
    ...
}

public int getNumber(String text) {
    return theMap.get(text);

    // I hope this will be, one day, forgotten. This is BAD.
    //for (String s : theMap.keySet())
    //  if (text.equals(s))
    //      return theMap.get(s);
    // return 0; // default for "item not found", or throw
}
```

thus `final String yourString = ""+getNumber(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());`

Conversion::String to integer is done by:

```
   int integer = Integer.parseInt(text);
```

integer to String

```
   String theString = ""+integer;
```

Comment: Yes, the strings in the spinner must be converted to numbers so a textview can tally them up. I still want the spinners to continue to display the strings but the conversion to the ints and the tallying must happen in the background. And I've tried what you posted, but there's an error in the first line, HashMap theMap = new HashMap<String, int>();.                                     Android studio doesn't like <String, int>, saying int cannot be of a primitive type.

Comment: Why are you setting up a `HashMap` and then iterating through each element? `theMap.get(text)` would do (with a `null` check for unknown strings).  Also, I think you need `HashMap<String,Integer>`, not `int`.

Comment: I've just googled primitive type, said the same thing you did triplehound for int/integer.

Comment: @KieranDee you are absolutely right, cant use primitives in collections, lib trove does that if needed

Comment: @TripleHound... whoa. why did.. ok, need a big coffee. I'm really sorry

Answer (score 0):

Create a Map like below:

```
Map<String,int> gradeScoreMap=new HashMap<String,int>();
gradeScoreMap.put("PASS",70);
gradeScoreMap.put("MERIT",70);
gradeScoreMap.put("DISTINCTION",70);
```

The above map will contains the mapping for your grade with score

create a getter for Map:

```
public String getgradeScoreMap(String grade) {
return gradeScoreMap.get(grade);
}
```

the above method will be used to fetch the score based on input grade.

Now use:

```
int score=-1;
if (spinner1.toString().equals("Pass")){
score =getgradeScoreMap(spinner1.toString());
}
```

The score will be your equivalent value for "PASS" i.e 70

Comment: I think you need `Map<String,Integer>` not `int`.

Comment: Thanks Imran, unfortunately public String getgradescoreMap(String grade) is returning an error where it cannot resolve symbol

Comment: Please share your segment of code and the exact error description.

Comment: Make your map as public static Map<String,int> gradeScoreMap=new HashMap<String,int>(); . In the same class you have to put the getter method. Initialize your map before using it . Also make your getgradeScoreMap() as static.